# Bootstrap 4: migrating pagination from Bootstrap3

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm porting an application from BS3 where the old pager looks like this:

[image: BS3 pager]

Here is the old code:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="pager">
        <li class="previous disabled"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span></a></li>
        <li>1/402</li>
        <li class="next"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Using bootstrap 4 doc, I've migrated to this

```
<nav>
    <ul class="pagination">
            <li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1"><span class="fa fa-arrow-left"></span></a></li>
        <li class="justify-content-center">1/395</li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#"><span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Which renders to this...

[image: Current BS4 rendering]

Anyone could help, on having the buttongs at the both end of the screen and rounded shape?

Thanks

EDIT 1: With the help of ZimSystem this is almost done, but still a rendering problem, the buttons are not circles but half / circle

[image: Almost done]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this..

```
<nav>
    <ul class="pagination justify-content-between">
        <li class="page-item flex-last"><a class="page-link rounded-circle" href="#"><span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></a></li>
        <li class="justify-content-center">1/395</li>
        <li class="page-item disabled flex-first"><a class="page-link rounded-circle" href="#" tabindex="-1"><span class="fa fa-arrow-left"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

`justify-content-between` makes the flexbox pagination stretch the full width, and then `rounded-circle` to make the links rounded like 3.x.

http://www.codeply.com/go/TliFbeUKC0

Comment: Thanks, it's almost that! the disabled class is not working if you remove the page-item on the first li tag. Adding the page-item makes a half rounded button

Comment: Updated the anwer, the only way to use `page-item` is to reverse the order using flexbox so that it properly applies the rounding.

Comment: Almost done, I've updated my question with the buttons rendering. Buttons are not circles, but disabled state is fine now!

Comment: There's is nothing else that can be done beyond overridding Bootstrap `.page-item:first-child .page-link, 
.page-item:last-child .page-link {
    border-radius: 50%;
}`